# Understanding a proof of Wedderburn decomposition in Weintraub's *Representation theory of finite groups*

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

In Chapter 2.2, *Representation Theory of Finite Groups* by S.Weintraub, the author gives a proof of Wedderburn decomposition as follows.

> **Theorem 2.16 (Wedderburn)** Let $R$ be a semisimple ring. Then there is a finite set $A$, a collection of integers $\{n_{\alpha}| \alpha \in A\}$, and division rings $\{D_{\alpha}|\alpha \in A\}$ such that $$R\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} \operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}}).$$
> **Proof:** We may write $R$ as a finite direct sum $$R\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} n_{\alpha} M_{\alpha},$$ where $\{M_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a set of representatives of the isomorphism classes of simple $R$-modules.
> By Schur's lemma, $\operatorname{End}_R(M_{\alpha})$ is a division algebra, which we denote by $E_{\alpha}$, for each $\alpha \in A$. Then $R$ is anti-isomorphic to $R^{op}$, and
> $$\begin{align} R^{op} &\cong \operatorname{End}_R(R) 
> \\&\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}, \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}) 
> \\&\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}\operatorname{Hom}_R(n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}, n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha})
> \\&\cong \prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_{\alpha}, M_{\alpha})
> \\&\cong \prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} E_{\alpha}
> \\&\cong \prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})
> \\&\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(n_{\alpha}E_{\alpha},n_{\alpha}E_{\alpha})
> \\&= \operatorname{End}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}}).
>  \end{align}$$
> Setting $D_{\alpha} = E_{\alpha}^{op}$, we complete the proof by observing that $\operatorname{End}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}})$ is anti-isomorphic to $\operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}})$.

My questions are:

1. Is there a $\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$ missing from the fourth isomorphism to the end?
2. How do one get $E_{\alpha}
   \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})$ as in the fifth isomorphism?

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is there a $\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$ missing from the fourth isomorphism to the end?

Yes, $\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$ is missing in all the lines after the fourth isomorphism.

> 2. How do one get $E_{\alpha}
>    \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})$ as in the fifth isomorphism?

This is another error: it should be $E_{\alpha}^{op}
\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})$ instead, which is just another instance of the isomorphism $R^{op}\cong \operatorname{End}_R(R)$ for any ring $R$ used at the beginning.

More important than these small errors, though, the entire proof has a much larger error: the chain of isomorphisms neglects the ring structure and so (as written) only yields an isomorphism of abelian groups $R\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} \operatorname{End}_{D_{\alpha}}(D_{\alpha}^{n_{\alpha}})$, not an isomorphism of rings!  In particular, the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_R(n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}, n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha})\cong \prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_{\alpha}, M_{\alpha})$ is only an isomorphism of abelian groups, not of rings (at least if you use the obvious product ring structure on the right side), and similarly for the isomorphism $\prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(n_{\alpha}E_{\alpha},n_{\alpha}E_{\alpha})$.  To get an isomorphism of rings you need to more carefully keep track of the ring structure you are using at each step, which ends up meaning you need to use a "matrix multiplication" ring structure on the middle steps that start with $\prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}}$.

Comment: Thank you. I also used to suspect that the author actually meant $E^{op}_{\alpha} \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})$, but if so, why he still took $D_{\alpha} = E_{\alpha}^{op}$ at the end of the proof？

Comment: Also, I have seen the double centralizer theorem in other texts of the same subject. Could the wedderburn theorem serve as a corollary of double centralizer theorem? Are they even equivalent?

Comment: I think you are right about the crucial problem. Could this proof be corrected? Or one has to use a distinct strategy (maybe analogue to the proof of double centralizer theorem) to prove it?

Comment: The idea of the proof is fine, you just have to keep track of the ring structure to check that the bijection it constructs actually preserves the ring structure.

Comment: You said it a lot better than i did +1

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there a $\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$ missing from the fourth isomorphism to the end?

Yes:

$$
\begin{align} R^{op} &\cong \operatorname{End}_R(R) 
\\&\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}, \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}) 
\\&\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}\operatorname{Hom}_R(n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}, n_{\alpha}M_{\alpha})
\\&\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}\prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \operatorname{Hom}_R(M_{\alpha}, M_{\alpha})
\\&\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}\prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} E_{\alpha}
\\&\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}\prod_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_{\alpha}} \operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha},E_{\alpha})
\\&\cong \bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}\operatorname{Hom}_{E_{\alpha}}(n_{\alpha}E_{\alpha},n_{\alpha}E_{\alpha})
\\
 \end{align}
$$

The last line

$\operatorname{End}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha})$

is clearly incorrect, though, because that is isomorphic to $E_\alpha$ (or its opposite ring, depending.)

But the last line would do better as

$\operatorname{End}_{E_{\alpha}}(n_\alpha E_{\alpha})$

(which just rewrites the line before it) and we'd recognize this as being isomorphic to $M_n(E_\alpha)$.

Actually with regards to the $\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$, I can't help but wonder if there's something slightly hidden in all of this homological calculus in talking about module isomorphisms and ring isomorphisms.  The appearance of the $\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$ was actually due to a $\prod_{\beta\in A}\bigoplus_{\alpha\in A}$ cancelling out, because $\hom(n_\alpha M_\alpha, n_\beta M_\beta)=\{0\}$ when $\alpha\neq \beta$. But at that rate it seems like $\prod_{\alpha\in A}$ would have been equivalent. Fortunately it doesn't matter for us because it can be shown that $|A|<\infty$ so the products and sums of modules coincide.

IMO, this is not as clear as convincing as arguing that a semisimple ring is a direct sum of simple semisimple rings, and then that simple semsimple ring is isomorphic to a matrix ring.  They get to the same place, but this big chain of isomorphisms does not explain much.

Comment: $\operatorname{End}_{E_{\alpha}}(E_{\alpha})$ in the last line is a typo of me, not of the author. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Although he may not be explaining what he is doing very clearly, I think that Waintraub is essentially correct (up to $^{\text{op}}$s which I think I agree he gets wrong, but didn't check carefully)

Precisely because I'd rather not track down $^{\text{op}}$'s carefully, I'd prefer to consider $R$ as a right $R$-module (which I will write as $R_R$) so that $R \cong \text{End}_R(R_R,R_R)$. Thus we assume that $R$ is *right*-semisimple rather than left-semisimple, but the fact that the two conditions are equivalent follows from Wedderburn's theorem readily.

**What (I think) Waintraub means**:

The crucial case is where $R$ has a unique isomorphism class of (right)simple object $S$ and so $R_R = S^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, so I will only address that case. But before examining the algebra $\text{End}_R(R_R,R_R)$ lets consider direct sums more generally:

Thus for now let $R$ be any ring and suppose the (right) $R$-module $M$ is a direct sum $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i$. Then if $P$ is any $R$-module, we have

$$
\text{Hom}_R(M,P) = \text{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i,P) \cong \prod_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_R(N_i,P),
$$
where the isomorphism $c_I$ is *canonical*: if $\varphi \in \text{Hom}(M,P)$ then its image $c_I(\varphi) =(\varphi\circ \iota_i)_{i \in I}$ where the map $\iota_i \colon N_i \to \bigoplus_{j\in I} N_j$ is the canonical inclusion. Indeed this isomorphism (for all $P$) determines $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i$ up to (canonical) isomorphism.

Similarly, there is a canonical map
$$
\iota_I \colon \bigoplus_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_R(P,N_i) \to \text{Hom}_R(P,\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i)
$$
given on each summand $\text{Hom}_R(P,N_i)$ by $\phi\mapsto \iota_i\circ \phi$. The map $\iota_I$ is always injective, and *provided* $I$ *is finite*, it is an isomorphism. This can be checked, for example, using the fact that finite direct sums coincide with finite products, hence
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Hom}_R(P,\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i) &= 
\text{Hom}_R(P,\prod_{i \in I} N_i) 
\cong \prod_{i\in I} \text{Hom}_{i \in I}(P,N_i) \\
&= \bigoplus_{i \in I} \text{Hom}_{i \in I}(P,N_i)
\end{split}
$$

It follows that, for a finite indexing set $I$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\text{End}(\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i) &\cong \prod_{i \in I}\text{Hom}_R(N_i,\bigoplus_{j\in I}N_j) \\
&\cong \prod_{i \in I}\bigoplus_{j\in I}\text{Hom}(N_i,N_j)
\end{split}
$$

Now we return to the case where $R$ is a (right) semisimple ring with  exactly one isomorphism class of simple (right) R-module, and let $S$ be such a simple module. Then $R_R \cong S^n$, so that $R \cong \text{Hom}_R(S^n,S^n)$.

Thus just as for $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i$ with $|I|<\infty$, letting $I= \{1,\ldots,n\}$ we see that
$$
R \cong \text{Hom}_R(S^n,S^n) \cong \prod_{j\in I_n}\text{Hom}(S,S^n) \cong \prod_{j \in I_n}\bigoplus_{i \in I_n} \text{Hom}(S,S)
$$
where the first isomorphism is given by $c_I$ and the second is given by $\iota_I^{-1}$ on each factor $\text{Hom}(S,S^n)$.

But now note that if $D=\text{Hom}_R(S,S)$, then using the isomorphism $D\cong \text{End}_D(D_D)$ (that is, $D$ is the endomorphism algebra of $D$ viewed as a right module over itself) and then using the maps $c_I$ and $\iota_I$ for $D$-modules we find
$$
\begin{split}
R \cong \prod_{j\in I_n}\bigoplus_{i \in I_n} D &= \prod_{j\in I_n}\bigoplus_{i\in I_n} \text{Hom}_D(D_D,D_D) \\
&\cong \prod_{j\in I_n} \text{Hom}(D_D,D_D^n) \\
&\cong \text{Hom}_D(D_D^n,D_D^n) = \text{End}_D(D_D^n).
\end{split}
$$
where this map *is an algebra homomorphism* precisely because the maps $c_I$ and $\iota_I$ are canonical.